# iPad does not do automatic screen rotation

Tags: ios, ipad, control-center, accelerometer

I've a problem with my iPad. After I updated to the lastest version of iOS the automatic screen rotation doesn't work anymore. I tried to restart my iPad because I supposed that it was only a system bug but it was not like I thought. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Is rotation lock on? Open Control Center by swiping from the top right of the screen (iOS 12+), then tap the rotation lock icon on the top row.

> If you see [image] in the status bar, Orientation Lock is on. To turn it off, swipe up from the bottom of the screen to open the Control Center, then tap [image].
>
> If you have an iPad with a Side Switch and don't see the Rotation Lock icon in Control Center, make sure that the Side Switch is off.

[If the screen doesn‘t rotate on your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204547)